# Tar file with date as name?

Tags: bash, tar

I'm trying to tar and gzip a file with date and time as the name:

```
date=$(date '+%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S');    
tar -zcf "$date".tar.gz repo/bin/
```

But I get back:

```
tar (child): Cannot connect to 17-08-2017_21: resolve failed
tar: Child returned status 128
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

What exactly is happening here and how can I fix?

Is tar trying to connect to the name as if it's an ip?

Comment: The [ISO standard for dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss, or `+%FT%T` in `date`'s syntax. In addition to giving the date in an unambiguous format, it sorts nicely!

Comment: @drewbenn with GNU date, also: `date --iso-8601=s` (but it also adds a timezone offset)

Comment: I would discourage from using colons. Something like ``20170818_122314`` or similar is sufficiently easy to recognize and/or parse. Colons cause trouble in various situations (you just discovered one).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes it is. At least for GNU tar, [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC107) says:

> If the archive file name includes a colon (`:`), then it is assumed to
>   be a file on another machine. If the archive file is `user@host:file`,
>   then *file* is used on the host *host*. The remote host is accessed using
>   the rsh program, with a username of *user*. If the username is omitted
>   (along with the `@` sign), then your user name will be used. (This is
>   the normal rsh behavior.).

It also provides a work-around:

```
--force-local
      Archive file is local even if it has a colon.
```

Comment: Shorter workaround: `tar zcf ./"$date".tar.gz ...` The leading path specification seems to make tar treat it as a regular file